# How to send state written in reducer to component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I just started learning react-redux. I am currently creating a login page. I wanted to send boolean state written in my reducer to my const, so when the state is true it will execute the code. But the state which i am send is returning undefined.

this is my reducer

```
const initState = {
  error: "",
  loading: false,
  loggedIn: false,
};

const authReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_PENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        loggedIn: false,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        loggedIn: true,
        error: "",
      };
    case LOGIN_ERROR:
      return {
        loading: false,
        loggedIn: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default authReducer;
```

this is my action

```
export function login(userInfo) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginPending());
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {
        userName: userInfo["Club"],
        password: userInfo["ClubPassword"],
      })
      .then((res) => {
        alert("Sucess");
        if (res.data.Result) {
            document.cookie = "token=" + res.data.Token;
            history.push("/");
        }
        dispatch(loginSuccess());
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(loginError(error.message));
      });
  };
}
```

I want to know how to bring my state of loggedin and use it in this private route

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          loggedIn ? <Component {...props} />
           : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        }
      />
    )
```

Edit: Is there any error on my index.js file

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"; // react-redux glues redux to react
import rootReducer from "./Store/Reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {/* providing store to the app */}
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: You should connect your component to redux with https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect or by using useSelector hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`useSelector` hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) from react-redux to get `loggedIn` from the Redux state:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const loggedIn = useSelector(state => state.loggedIn)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        loggedIn ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      }
    />
  )
}
``
```

Comment: do i need to export any component or function before using useSelector? or do i need use connect in my app component(this function is in my app component ). Because I used this method just before posting this question and it gave me. **Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

Comment: additionally when I try to console.log this it gives me undefined

Comment: If elsewhere you are doing `import PrivateRoute from "/some/path";` then yes, this file needs to do `export default` for the component.

Comment: my `PrivateRoute` is inside `render()` under App Component. So it is not exported to anywhere or imported

Comment: It should not be inside another `render` function. It can be pulled out to the root of the file.

Comment: it seems the problem was actually occurred when when i tried to add route on the my component.